# Getting error on server due to anonymous functions issue in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using "google-api-php-client" library which is working fine on local system but it's giving following error on server as it's version is 5.2!

```
syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'
```

So I have two questions here, if we can fix this error by doing some changes in code to make it work with this function? Below is the code of autoload.php

```
spl_autoload_register(
function ($className) {
  $classPath = explode('_', $className);
  if ($classPath[0] != 'Google') {
    return;
  }
  // Drop 'Google', and maximum class file path depth in this project is 3.
  $classPath = array_slice($classPath, 1, 2);

  $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . implode('/', $classPath) . '.php';
  if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    require_once($filePath);
  }
}
);
```

but I'm not sure how to change the above to solve this issue and also is there any library which can run on php version 5.2? As if I use this, it might be possible that it start giving error on some other functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulCrovella yes you are right, but the project I'm working on is built in this version and upgrading version is very risky as it might disturb everything so it will be our last option to upgrade. Is there any other way which could help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your php version not knows about anonymous functions or closures. Try to use named one:

```
function autoloadGoogleApi($className) {
  $classPath = explode('_', $className);
  if ($classPath[0] != 'Google') {
    return;
  }
  // Drop 'Google', and maximum class file path depth in this project is 3.
  $classPath = array_slice($classPath, 1, 2);

  $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . implode('/', $classPath) . '.php';
  if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    require_once($filePath);
  }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloadGoogleApi');
```

Still, I'm also want to point out, that php version you specifying is **very old**, so I'm suggesting to really **consider option of upgrading**.

**UPD:** [3v4l test](https://3v4l.org/l18op)

Comment: it fixed the issue but as expected started giving other errors. upgrading version might be the only solution left. Is there any library available for 5.2 version? I searched but didn't found anything yet.

Comment: @ÛmÄîrMÄlîk It is better to patch up to new php version. It might be painful and slow process, but most of the libraries already did it. Or you will be drawn in version compability problem further, if you will not start patching. Consider.